# Pass array from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to pass an array from javascript to PHP. 
The error message says:

> **NULL Warning:** *Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/jsontest/json_receive.php on line 10*

Anything wrong with my code?

```
<script>
function sendData(){
    var arr= [{  
        "city" : "Brussels",  
        "age" : 25  
    },
    {  
        "city" : "Antwerp",  
        "age" : 40  
    }]; 

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "json_receive.php",
       datatype: 'JSON',
       data: {arr: JSON.stringify(arr)},
       success: function(data){
            console.log("success:",data);
        },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
            console.error("error:",errMsg);
       }
    });
}
```

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST["arr"]);
// will echo the JSON.stringified - string:
echo $_POST["arr"];
// will echo the json_decode'd object
var_dump($data);
//traversing the whole object and accessing properties:

print_r($data);
foreach($data as $cityObject){
    echo "City: " . $cityObject->city . ", Age: " . $cityObject->age . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: And what does all the echoing, dumping and printing show you ?

Comment: try `$data = json_decode($_POST["arr"],true);`

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: What if you just change `data: {arr: JSON.stringify(arr)}` into `data: {arr : arr}`.

Comment: I've tested your code on my server as it works as expected, no errors.

Comment: @QinLin are you still having problems with your code?

Comment: what you are getting by `var_dump`??

Comment: What re you trying to achieve with this code ? it seems you're passing the same data back and forward. Also, as I said previously, **there's nothing wrong with your code**.

Comment: I agree with @PedroLobito , your code seems fine.

Comment: @PedroLobito  I am trying to use the code to test how I can pass an array to PHP from javascript. When I run the PHP code. I still got nothing but "NULL Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/jsontest/json_receive.php on line 10". If it works as expected, some data should be printed in the page right? Or is it I am using localhost so I cannot get it correct? Anw thank you guys, I am new to PHP, please bear with me if my questions are too naive.

Comment: check the console, nothing will be printed because you're just logging to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said on the comments, You're code looks **good** and **works** (I've tested it), the problem is that you're expecting something to be printed on the page but your `Ajax` `success` function only uses the **console**.

```
   success: function(data){
        console.log("success:",data);
    }
```

Comment: The console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", referring to the line $.Ajax ({

Comment: It seems that your jquery isn't included correctly `<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> `

Comment: Yeah, the javascript file works as expected. Still got nothing printed out on the php page even if I commented the 'console' statements. Is there a better method for me to print the data in php?

Comment: You need to get the result from the php and assign it to any element of your page , check a sample of that http://stackoverflow.com/a/18064824/797495

Comment: I intend to go to the php page with datas after executing the javascript. However, now the data all not there when I go to php page. How can I achieve this? Can you advise?