# Continue in javascript after php returns true or false

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, return

I need some help. I try to do registration and because I need to refresh only the registration part on page, I must use ajax. And here is the problem. When I submit the form, ajax loads different file, where is registration part in php. In php I have some variables, which I use to change color of particular inputs, if there was an error. But, because the php is in other file, I cant access the variables from file, where the ajax is and change the colors. And if I try place script, which changes the colors, in the file, where php is, it dont execute, because I somewhere stop php with for example "return false".

Do you know please, what I can do with this? Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english.

This is the ajax part

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#registerUser").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var typedEmail = $("#registerEmail").val(),
                typedPassword = $("#registerPassword").val(),
                typedRepeatedPassword = $("#registerRepeatedPassword").val();
                submittedForm = $("#registerSubmit").val();

                $("#registerMessage").load("accountRegistration.php", {
                    email: typedEmail,
                    password: typedPassword,
                    repeatedPassword: typedRepeatedPassword,
                    submit: submittedForm
                });

            });

        });

    </script>
```

This is the php file

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    require_once "autoload.php";

    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $repeatedPassword = $_POST["repeatedPassword"];
    $emailError = false;
    $passwordError = false;
    $repeatedPasswordError = false;

    if(empty($email)){
      $emailError = true;
    }

    if(empty($password)){
      $passwordError = true;
    }

    if(empty($repeatedPassword)){
      $repeatedPasswordError = true;
    }

    if(strlen($password) < 8){
      $passwordError = true;
    }

    if($password != $repeatedPassword){
      $repeatedPasswordError = true;
    }

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $emailError = true;
    }

    if($emailError == true || $passwordError == true || $repeatedPasswordError == true){
      echo("<span class='errorMessage'>Vyplňte správně všechna políčka!</span>");
      return false;
    }

    $registration = new DatabaseOperations;
    if($registration->selectOneRow("users", "userID", "email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR)){
      echo("<span class='errorMessage'>Tento email už někdo používá.</span>");
      return false;
    }

    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if($registration->insertOneRow("users", array("email", "password"), array($email, $passwordHash))){
      echo("<span class='successMessage'>Registrace proběhla úspěšně.</span>");
      return true;
    } else{
      echo("<span class='errorMessage'>Něco se pokazilo. Zkuste to prosím znovu.</span>");
      return false;
    }



  } else{
    echo ("Stala se chyba. Zkuste to prosím znovu.");
  }

<script>

$("#registerEmail, #registerPassword, #registerRepeatedPassword").removeClass("inputError");

var emailError = "<?php echo(isset($emailError) ? $emailError : '') ?>";
var passwordError = "<?php echo(isset($registerPassword) ? $registerPassword : '') ?>";
var repeatedPasswordError = "<?php echo(isset($registerRepeatedPassword) ? $registerRepeatedPassword : '') ?>";
console.log(emailError);
console.log(passwordError);
console.log(repeatedPasswordError);

if(emailError == true){
  $("#registerEmail").addClass("inputError");
}

if(passwordError == true){
  $("#registerPassword").addClass("inputError");
}

if(repeatedPasswordError == true){
  $("#registerRepeatedPassword").addClass("inputError");
}

if(passwordError == true || repeatedPasswordError == true){
  $("#registerPassword").val("");
  $("#registerRepeatedPassword").val("");
}

</script>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="signUp">
            <h1>registrace</h1>
            <form method='POST' name="register" id="registerUser">
                <p id="registerMessage"></p>
                <input type='email' id='registerEmail' name='email' placeholder='Váš email'>
                <input type='password' id='registerPassword' name='password' placeholder='Vaše heslo (min. 8 znaků)'>
                <input type='password' id='registerRepeatedPassword' name='repeatedPassword' placeholder='Ověření hesla'>
                <input type='submit' id='registerSubmit' name='' value='REGISTROVAT'>
            </form>
            <p>MÁM ÚČET A&nbsp;<a href="#null"  class="changeForm">CHCI SE PŘIHLÁSIT</a><p>
        </div>
```

Comment: What you getting in response? What your ajax call returns, any error any kind of response?

Comment: When I add function(response){console.log(response);} into ajax, it displays only <span> from echo in php. A have tried to change for example return false to return $emailError, but nothing happened.

Comment: You have to try `$.ajax` function with `html` dataType

Comment: I can try a different method, but I dont know which, which is safe etc..

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064666/update-div-with-jquery-ajax-response-html

Answer (score 0):

Ajax with html does the same. It returns only what is in "echo"

```
$.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "accountRegistration.php",
                    data: {
                        email: typedEmail,
                        password: typedPassword,
                        repeatedPassword: typedRepeatedPassword,
                        submit: submittedForm
                    },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(errors){
                        console.log("Errors: " + errors);
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it like this..

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#registerUser").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var typedEmail = $("#registerEmail").val(),
                typedPassword = $("#registerPassword").val(),
                typedRepeatedPassword = $("#registerRepeatedPassword").val();
                submittedForm = $("#registerSubmit").val();

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "accountRegistration.php",
                    data: {
                        email: typedEmail,
                        password: typedPassword,
                        repeatedPassword: typedRepeatedPassword,
                        submit: submittedForm
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(results){

                        $("#registerMessage").html(results["message"]);

                        $("#registerEmail, #registerPassword, #registerRepeatedPassword").removeClass("inputError");

                        var emailError = results["emailError"];
                        var passwordError = results["passwordError"];
                        var repeatedPasswordError = results["repeatedPasswordError"];

                        if(emailError == true){
                          $("#registerEmail").addClass("inputError");
                        }

                        if(passwordError == true){
                          $("#registerPassword").addClass("inputError");
                        }

                        if(repeatedPasswordError == true){
                          $("#registerRepeatedPassword").addClass("inputError");
                        }

                        if(passwordError == true || repeatedPasswordError == true){
                          $("#registerPassword").val("");
                          $("#registerRepeatedPassword").val("");
                        }

                    }
                });

            });

        });

    </script>




<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    registerUser();
  }

  function registerUser(){
    require_once "autoload.php";

    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $repeatedPassword = $_POST["repeatedPassword"];
    $emailError = false;
    $passwordError = false;
    $repeatedPasswordError = false;

    if(empty($email)){
      $emailError = true;
    }

    if(empty($password)){
      $passwordError = true;
    }

    if(empty($repeatedPassword)){
      $repeatedPasswordError = true;
    }

    if(strlen($password) < 8){
      $passwordError = true;
    }

    if($password != $repeatedPassword){
      $repeatedPasswordError = true;
    }

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $emailError = true;
    }

    if($emailError == true || $passwordError == true || $repeatedPasswordError == true){
      echo (json_encode(
        array("emailError" => $emailError,
         "passwordError" => $passwordError,
         "repeatedPasswordError" => $repeatedPasswordError,
         "message" => "<span class='errorMessage'>Vyplňte správně všechna políčka!</span>"
        )));
      return false;
    }

    $registration = new DatabaseOperations;
    if($registration->selectOneRow("users", "userID", "email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR)){
      echo(json_encode(array("message" => "<span class='errorMessage'>Tento email už někdo používá.</span>")));
      return false;
    }

    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if($registration->insertOneRow("users", array("email", "password"), array($email, $passwordHash))){
      echo(json_encode(array("message" => "<span class='successMessage'>Registrace proběhla úspěšně.</span>")));
      return true;
    } else{
      echo(json_encode(array("message" => "<span class='errorMessage'>Něco se pokazilo. Zkuste to prosím znovu.</span>")));
      return false;
    }

  }

 ?>
```